# Serial communication using Arduino and RS 232 cable

Tags: arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I am trying to control KEITHLEY Electrometer 6517B using Arduino by sending the SCPI commands but I am not getting any input. I bought an RS232 converter and using the TX and RX pins. Below is the code that I'm using.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial1.begin(19200); // port that RS232 is connected to
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available()) {
    int inByte = Serial1.read();
    Serial.write(inByte);
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    char ser = Serial.read();
    Serial1.write(ser);
  }

}
```

I did the following with Python but it was working there but not here.

Comment: What do you mean with Python? You can't run Python on an Arduino.

Comment: Not sure of the point of this code.  Looks like simple read-write loopback between two parts.  What can be the outcome of this with no outside input?  Is there something you're not showing us?

Comment: Have you made sure you didn't mix the RX/TX up? Happens all the time to me. Also, what converter are you using?

Comment: what is "the following" you mention? nothing is following after that sentence...